# How to loc 5 rows before and 5 rows after value 1 in column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe , i want to change loc 5 rows before and 5 rows after flag value is 1.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,1,3,4,7,8,11,1,15,20,15,16,87],
                 'flag':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]})

expect_output

df1_before =pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,4,7,8],
                 'flag':[0,0,0,0,1]})
df1_after =pd.DataFrame({'A':[8,11,1,15,20],
                 'flag':[1,1,1,0,0]})
```

do same process for all three flag 1

Comment: how do you want the result to be stored? here I can see you want 2 dataframes for the first flag, but are you looking to do it in a loop? are you performing any operation on the selected rows?

Comment: @ Ben.T   yes i will perform some operation on the selected rows

Comment: @Ben.T in simple words , When in column flag find value is 1 get 5 rows before and 5 rows after and process , and then go to find next 1 and do same .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one easy way is to loop over the index where the flag is 1 and select the rows you want with loc:

```
l = len(df)
for idx in df[df.flag.astype(bool)].index:
    dfb = df.loc[max(idx-4,0):idx]
    dfa = df.loc[idx:min(idx+4,l)]
    #do stuff
```

the `min` and `max` function are to ensure the boundary are not passed in case you have a flag=1 within the first or last 5 rows. Note also that with `loc`, if you want 5 rows, you need to use `+/-4` on idx to get the right segment.

That said, depending on what your actual `#do stuff` is, you might want to change tactic. Let's say for example, you want to calculate the difference between the sum of A over the 5 rows after and the 5 rows before. you could use `rolling` and `shift`:

```
df['roll'] = df.rolling(5)['A'].sum()
df.loc[df.flag.astype(bool), 'diff_roll'] = df['roll'].shift(-4) - df['roll']
print (df)
     A  flag   roll  diff_roll
0    2     0    NaN        NaN
1    1     0    NaN        NaN
2    3     0    NaN        NaN
3    4     0    NaN        NaN
4    7     0   17.0        NaN
5    8     1   23.0       32.0 #=55-23, 55 is the sum of A of df_after and 23 df_before
6   11     1   33.0       29.0
7    1     1   31.0       36.0
8   15     0   42.0        NaN
9   20     0   55.0        NaN
10  15     0   62.0        NaN
11  16     0   67.0        NaN
12  87     0  153.0        NaN
```